# How do you left align a div?

Tags: html, css

I Have tried to left align a div by using:

```
<div class="col-md-3 float-left">
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: left;">
```

nothing I try is working?

I tried the float now and the !important and still not working, so here is more of my code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Branch</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BranchName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BranchName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BranchName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="float: left !important;">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class=" col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is a pic to see what I mean.  It looks terrible with the checkbox and the textbox so far from their labels.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some mode context to the question. Are the div contained in another element? What is the CSS used?

Comment: @Hoshts I added more context

Comment: @Andrew where would I get a jsfiddle from?

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell you much without more code or a more specific description of the problem. Regardless of that, my assumption is that you need the contents of a div left aligned? By the class names you are using, I assume you are using Bootstrap. In that case, try adding this class to your div:

```
text-left
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
style="text-align: left !important;"
```

If the second one works, you have CSS that is written somewhere else that is predominate, try to find this CSS and remove/change it. If you are confused about this, read up on [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Do not leave the `!important` attached for no reason; in general this is considered bad practice.

reference:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Answer (score 0):

You want to allign a div, and not a text. So you can use:

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="float:left">
```

Answer (score 0):

For left align of a div

```
<div style="float: left;"></div>
```

for left align of a text

```
<p style="text-align:left;"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="col-md-1">
```

instead of

```
<div class="col-md-2">
```

on your Label Div's
The gap should come from the size of the col-md-2. If you choose col-md-1 the gap should be smaller.

Comment: Phil, the problem with that is on other pages where I use the same code, some of the labels are longer forcing them on to another line and also looks terrible.  I already tested that.